# Flash Develop with Flex4.6: How to match width and height of SWF to resolution automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop, flex4.6

My question is simple, but I haven't found any answer that fits my problem. I have this in the main class:

```
[SWF(frameRate = "60", width = "900", height = "600", backgroundColor = "0x333333")]
```

I want to change the width and height so they match the resolution of the screen automatically. Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY return the width and height of the computer screen, but I cant just do:

```
[SWF(frameRate = "60", width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX.toString(), height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY.toString(), backgroundColor = "0x333333")]
```

because it returns the error: "Error: Invalid metadata".

Is it possible to do what I ask? And if it is possible, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you run SWF in browser or standalone Flash Player?

Comment: Standalone Flash Player, sorry for not pointing that out.

Comment: Try to set up stage.displayState to StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN. So the width and height of the SWF file will be equal to the screen width and height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, if I do that without modifying the SWF properties I still only see an area of  900x600, and the rest is filled with the background color.

Comment: Try to set up stage.scaleMode to ScaleMode.SHOW_ALL.

Comment: Tried, but nothing changes :(